# Burp Sequencer, how to set significance level

Tags: entropy, burp

I read this article [How the randomness tests work](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/sequencer/tests) and it appears the **significance level** for the analysis can be configured but I can't find any UI element or documentation to make that change.

Answer (score 0):

I found no way of configuring a significance level but the report generated by the sequencer provides results for multiple significance levels.

[image]